# My code gives Key error beyond a limit

Tags: python, python-3.x, factorial, keyerror

I was solving Project Euler [problem 34](http://www.mathblog.dk/project-euler-34-factorial-digits/)

My code gives is as follows:

```
import functools

limit = int(input())

factDict = { 0:1, 1:1, 2:2, 3:6, 4:24, 5:120, 6:720, 7:5040, 8:40320, 9:362880 }

for i in range(10, limit):
    listNum = list(map(int, list(str(i))))
    #print(listNum)
    sumFact = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: factDict[x] + factDict[y], listNum)
    if(sumFact%i == 0):
        print(i)
```

It works fine until 140 and then gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "solution.py", line 10, in <module>
    sumFact=functools.reduce(lambda x, y: factDict[x]+factDict[y], listNum)
  File "solution.py", line 10, in <lambda>
    sumFact=functools.reduce(lambda x, y: factDict[x]+factDict[y], listNum)
KeyError: 25
```

I printed the list too and found there is no problem there.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not using `functools.reduce()` correctly.

This: `functools.reduce(lambda x, y: factDict[x] + factDict[y], listNum)` applied to [1, 4, 0] will (try to) calculate:

```
factDict[factDict[1] + factDict[4]] + factDict[0]
```

resulting in this index error (factDict[1] + factDict[4] being equal to 25).

According [to the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

> The left argument, x, is the accumulated value

So if you use factDict[x] you will replace the accumulated value by its factorial (not what you want).

So you have to leave x 'alone'.

Then, to initialize to something "neutral", you can just use 0, this way, it will actually compute (for 140): `0 + factDict[1] + factDict[4] + factDict[0]`

So finally:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import functools

limit = int(input())

factDict = { 0:1, 1:1, 2:2, 3:6, 4:24, 5:120, 6:720, 7:5040, 8:40320, 9:362880 }

for i in range(10, limit):
    listNum = list(map(int, list(str(i))))
    #print(listNum)
    sumFact = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x + factDict[y], listNum, 0)
    if(sumFact == i):
        print("Found: " + str(i))
```

Moreover I changed the last test in `sumFact == i` since you're looking for numbers equal to the sum of their factorials, not being a divisor of the sum of their factorials. (As stated in the comments, you can use the test you like).

PS this doesn't give a lot of results:

```
$ ./test_script.py
1000000
Found: 145
Found: 40585
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I realized after your explanation. But the question states divisor, rendering your last edit not necessary as 19 satisfies. Thanks for clarifying anyway. Also is there a better way using reduce?

Comment: Hum, don't see any divisor in the question or problem 34, but this last test can be set as fit your needs anyway. Yes I found a better way, I edit the answer.

Comment: Done. Don't hesitate to accept my answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

the reduce method does not work as you intend. Visit https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce

```
sumFact = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: factDict[x] + factDict[y], listNum).
```

in that expression x is the accumulated value and y is the update value from the iterable (listNum).
When the exception occures, the value of listNum is [1,4,0]. the calculations made by the reduce function at that moment is then :

```
accum_value = factDict[1]+factDict[4] # accum_value is set to 25
accum_value = factDict[accum_value]+factDict[0] # Keyerror factDict does not have the key 25.
```

A way to correct this is to set an initializer into the reduce function like this.

```
import functools
limit = int(input())
factDict = { 0:1, 1:1, 2:2, 3:6, 4:24, 5:120, 6:720, 7:5040, 8:40320, 9:362880 }

for i in range(10, limit):
    listNum = list(map(int, list(str(i))))
    #print(listNum)
    sumFact = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x + factDict[y], listNum[1:len(listNum)],factDict[listNum[0]])
    #print sumFact
    if(sumFact%i == 0):
        print(i)
```

Note that this code will display numbers which are devided by the sum of the factorial of thier digits.